# Flutter my Listview is not scrolling even I have alwayscrollable

Tags: flutter, listview, user-interface, flutter-layout, scrollable

I dont understand what's causing the error really.

My code is in a seperated class with a returning Widget method, the that method returns a Stack which envelopes my Listview.

Note: When I copy the Container with a Listview and modified the appropriate values of course; then paste in a new project with A Stack as a parent again, its seems to work fine.

Here is the code:

```
AddStockUI(){
    Widget getAddStockUI() {
        final mediaSize = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
        return Container(
          width: mediaSize.width,
          height: mediaSize.height,
          color: Colors.white,
          child: Stack(
            children: <Widget>[
              //Head - image
              Container(
                width: mediaSize.width * .8,
                height: mediaSize.height * .2,
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                  left: mediaSize.width * .1,
                  right: mediaSize.width * .1,
                  top: mediaSize.height * .05,
                ),
                child: Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Container(
                      width: mediaSize.width * .37,
                      height: mediaSize.height * .2,
                      child: Image.asset(
                        'assets/images/image_add_image.png',
                        width: mediaSize.width * .37,
                        height: mediaSize.height * .2,
                        filterQuality: FilterQuality.high,
                        fit: BoxFit.fill,
                      ),
                    ),
                    Spacer(),
                    Container(
                        constraints: BoxConstraints(
                            maxHeight: mediaSize.height * .2,
                            maxWidth: mediaSize.width * .37),
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                        child: ListView.builder(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                            physics: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                            itemCount: myMapDesc.keys.length + 1,
                            itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctx, int index) {
                              if (index == 0) {
                                return Container(
                                  width: mediaSize.width * .35,
                                  height: mediaSize.height * .03,
                                  child: Row(
                                    children: <Widget>[
                                      Center(
                                          child: Container(
                                        width: mediaSize.width * .14,
                                        child: AutoSizeText(
                                          "variation",
                                          style: TextStyle(color: myLightDarkColor),
                                          maxFontSize: 14,
                                          minFontSize: 12,
                                          maxLines: 1,
                                        ),
                                      )),
                                      Spacer(),
                                      Center(
                                          child: Container(
                                        width: mediaSize.width * .1,
                                        child: AutoSizeText(
                                          "value",
                                          style: TextStyle(color: myLightDarkColor),
                                          maxFontSize: 14,
                                          minFontSize: 12,
                                          maxLines: 1,
                                        ),
                                      )),
                                      Spacer(),
                                      Container(width: mediaSize.width * .11)
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                );
                              } else {
                                return Container(
                                  margin:
                                      EdgeInsets.only(top: mediaSize.height * .025),
                                  width: mediaSize.width * .35,
                                  height: mediaSize.height * .03,
                                  child: Row(
                                    children: <Widget>[
                                      Center(
                                          child: Container(
                                        width: mediaSize.width * .1,
                                        child: AutoSizeText(
                                          myMapDesc.keys
                                              .toList()[index - 1]
                                              .toString(),
                                          style: TextStyle(color: myLightDarkColor),
                                          maxFontSize: 14,
                                          minFontSize: 12,
                                          maxLines: 1,
                                        ),
                                      )),
                                      Spacer(),
                                      Center(
                                          child: Container(
                                        width: mediaSize.width * .1,
                                        child: AutoSizeText(
                                          myMapDesc.values
                                              .toList()[index - 1]
                                              .toString(),
                                          style: TextStyle(color: myLightDarkColor),
                                          maxFontSize: 14,
                                          minFontSize: 12,
                                          maxLines: 1,
                                        ),
                                      )),
                                      Spacer(),
                                      Icon(
                                        Icons.remove_circle,
                                        color: Colors.red,
                                      )
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                );
                              }
                            }))
                  ],
                ),
              ),
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping your ListView with a SingleChildScrollView

Comment: what about wrapping the parent widget?

Comment: The very first container??

Comment: last try.. wrapping your `Stack()` widget with `SingleChildScrollView` if this doesnt work , im sorry im out of ideas... :(